the number of distinct ways in which $N$ can be expressed as a sum

Suppose that $N$ is a positive integer. Let $S(N)$ denotes the number of distinct ways in which $N$ can be expressed as a sum of consecutive positive integers. Prove that $S(N)$ is equal to the number of odd divisors of $N$.


I tried creating a bijection as mentioned in the title. I took an example of $n=9$, for which we get, $(9),(2,3,4),(4,5)$, which is exactly the number of odd divisiors, which are 1,3,9, again for 7, which has odd divisiors $1,7$ we get the following representations: $(7),(3,4)$, but I'm not able to see any bijection that exists here, how do we create a bijection?

I'll write a rough sketch of a proof here (not entirely rigorous):
Note that any group of consecutive numbers with an odd number of terms must be divisible by the number of terms, and any group of consecutive numbers with an even number of terms must be divisible by the sum of the middle two terms. For example, $7 \mid (8,9,10,11,12,13,14)$ and $9 \mid (2,3,4,5,6,7)$.
Now, consider any odd factor  of $N$. If the factor, which we call $d$, has the property that $N \geq d\cdot \frac{d+1}{2}$, then we can express $N$ with a sum of an odd number of consecutive terms.
For example, in $30$, where we have $3$ as a divisor, we can associate the odd number $3$ with $(9,10,11).$ This set cannot get out of range because $\frac{N}{d}-\frac{d-1}{2} = \frac{2N-d(d-1)}{2d} \geq 1$.
Generally, for each $d$, we express the set $$\{\frac{N}{d}-
\frac{d-1}{2}, \frac{N}{d}-\frac{d-3}{2},...,\frac{N}{d},...,\frac{N}{d}+\frac{d-3}{2},\frac{N}{d}+\frac{d-1}{2}\}$$
Notice that this set is always unique as we move the middle term up the whole thing  increases so there can be at most one "sweet spot".
Otherwise, we must have $N \leq d\cdot \frac{d-1}{2}$. We can express this as
$$\{\frac{d-1}{2}-\frac{N}{d}+1,\frac{d-1}{2}-\frac{N}{d}+2,...,\frac{d-1}{2},\frac{d+1}{2},...,\frac{d+1}{2}+\frac{N}{d}-2,\frac{d+1}{2}+\frac{N}{d}-1\}$$
And this can always happen as $\frac{d-1}{2}-\frac{N}{d}+1 \geq 1$. Similarly to above, there can only be at most one "sweet spot".
Since we have constructed the sets up to the number of odd divisors, now it suffies to prove that there are none left.
Assume, for the sake of contradiction that there is another set with consecutive terms. We now split into cases:
Case 1: The number of terms are odd. Then, let the length of that set be $L$. It is clear that $L \mid N$. We know that $L=d$ for some $d$ that we already have constructed. If this one is not different to the original construction, then there is a contradiction as we supposed there was at least one other construction apart from the original construction. Thus, this one is different to the original construction, meaning that there are two "sweet spots" for one of the $d$, which cannot happen.
Case 2: The number of terms are even. Then, consider the sum of the middle two terms. Call this sum $S$. It is clear that $S \mid N$. It is also true that $S$ must be odd. Thus, we have already covered $S$ in our original construction, and so we can finish off from here.
Thus, we have established a bijection between the odd factors of $N$ and the number of consecutive sets, as we have proved there exists at least $S(N)$ consecutive sets and no more.
P.S. I did write this at like midnight so there might be a couple of errors

Suppose $N$ is a sum of $l$ consecutive numbers:
$$\begin{align}
N&=k+(k+1)+\dots+(k+l-1)\\
&=\frac {l(k+k+l-1)}2\\
&=\frac {l(l+2k-1)}2.
\end{align}$$
So we have $$2N=l(l+2k-1).$$
We see that $2N$ is presented as a product of two natural numbers of different parity (because their difference is $2k-1$, which is an odd number). So the number of solutions of this equation equals to the number of odd divisors of $2N$. This, in turn, equals to the number of odd divisors of $N$.
